# Extra operation button in django admin panel

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to add some buttons to do a lot of database operations at once, and I want to place those button(s) at (1) place. How to do that?

[image: Django Admin Panel]

Extra explains:

- What I want to do is to clear all "Logs" and set access count (an integer) to 0 in every object inside "Shortcuts.
- I'm too lazy to do so manually.

Comment: Can you share admin.py file  ?

Comment: https://github.com/Emojigit/shortcuts/blob/master/main/admin.py